# drupal how to show custom profile field

Tags: drupal, field, profile, edit

i added a profile field to registration form. how to show in ***edit registration (account)*** form . i wrote a module for edit account in that *$form* [function editregistration_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) ] doesn't contain the values of custom profile fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the core Profile module, profile fields have a setting that you can check off that say 'Show in registration form' when you edit them.

Comment: It should appear there too. If you've added them to a Profile Category, you need to output $tabs2 in your page.tpl.php or you won't see them. Then again, this is only if you are using the core Profile module which makes this all really simple.

Answer (score -1):

The name of that function looks a bit funny. What's your module called? And the form id?

There's a bit about naming hook_form_alter functions in the 'Writing the Module' section of this: http://www.chromaticsites.com/blog/drupal-tutorial-form-overrides-and-element-specific-validations/